# Dexie.js Does not follow the code execution order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this library to perform functions IndexedDB more easily, but it does not follow at all the execution order and this makes my work not script (this code is only an example to show that he did not follow the order of execution)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ph5ebrw4/ (see the console)

Dexie code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/master/dist/latest/Dexie.js

```
var db = new Dexie('teste');
var atual_sequence = 0;

db.version(1).stores({sequences: '++id,of'});

db.open().catch(function(error){
}); 

db.sequences.where("of").equalsIgnoreCase('0').count(function (count) {
                 atual_sequence = count;
                 console.warn(atual_sequence);

});
db.sequences.add({of: '0'});
```

He runs  `console.log('ds: '+atual_sequence);` before you get the atual_sequence, is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language you have attempted to use in your question is not very clear. Who is he? Where is `console.log('ds: '+atual_sequence);` run from?

In any case I hope this code snippet helps to solve your problem. Notice the use of the `then` which helps to run the code once the first operation is done.

```
db.sequences.where("of").equalsIgnoreCase('0').count(function (count) {
    atual_sequence = count;
    console.warn(atual_sequence);
}).then( function() {
    db.sequences.add({of: '0'});
});
```